# How can I add an icon in a SharePoint document library template?

Tags: image, sharepoint, icons, document

i want to insert a image in a sharepoint document library template.

It should appear when I click Site Settings -> More Options -> in the Library selection.

I tried to manipulate the manifest.xml - File with the ImageUrl-Tag and it didn't help.

Is it possible? I've searched for many days an can't find anything.

THX

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a preview image to a custom SharePoint document library you created, correct?

I'm assuming you have created a list template (specifically a document library template). In the `elements.xml` of that template you have the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439434.aspx) attribute which represents the preview image.

Here is an example `elements.xml` for a custom document library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <ListTemplate
        Name="MyList"
        Type="10012"
        BaseType="1"
        OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
        SecurityBits="11"
        Sequence="110"
        DisplayName="My List"
        Description=""
        Hidden="false"
        Image="/_layouts/images/itdl.png"
        DocumentTemplate="121"/>
</Elements>
```

The document library will be shown with the image located at `/_layouts/images/itdl.png` as its preview image. You said you tried settings the `ImageUrl` attribute - this doesn't exist for a list template, though it would exist when you were creating a web template ([see this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041790/setting-preview-image-for-sharepoint-2010-custom-web-template)).

Comment: Hi, ich habe die Dokumentenbibliothek als Vorlage heruntergeladen und bekomme eine .stp-Datei. Darin enthalten ist nur eine manifest.xml. Dort habe ich das mit Image="/_layouts/images/bild.png" probiert. Geht aber leider auch nicht. Wenn ich meine Vorlage in Weitere Optionen auswählen möchte, erhalte ich immer das selbe bild: http://SEVER/_layouts/images/ltfl.png . Dieses möchte ich ändern. Soll ich eine feature.xml Datei erstellen?

Comment: The official language on SO is English, @grekko. The templates generated by SharePoint should not be edited, that's why you would have to go through the hassle to rename the *.stp file to *.cab extract the manifest.xml and do your changes there. You should create your own list template using Visual Studio.

Comment: That's what I did. I downloaded the template, the .stp file, extracted the file and changed the manifest.xml. Unfortunately, nothing worked.